# What function data type should I use to return a vector.push_back()?

Tags: c++, function, vector, types

```
string yesno(string holder ,vector<string> symptom)
{
    if(holder == "Y" || holder == "y"){
        return symptom.push_back("Y");
    }
    else if(holder == "N" || holder == "n"){
        return symptom.push_back("N");
    }
    else{
        cout <<"Wrong input" << endl;
        return symptom.push_back("-");
    }
}
```

So this is my function for when I'm asking a user are they experiencing a certain symptom and then ask for Y/y or N/n for an answer.

The `if` blocks in the function detects the upper and lower case of Y or N and then I'm returning `symptom.push_back()` as "Y" or "N" but I'm getting this error:

> error: could not convert
> 'symptom.std::vectorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char
> ::push_back(std::__cxx11::basic_string(((const char*)"Y"), std::allocator()))' from 'void' to 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka
> 'std::__cxx11::basic_string'}|

Comment: `void yesno(string holder ,vector<string> symptom)` Literally your only option. Whatever you are trying to do, this is not the solution.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `if(holder == "Y" || holder == "y") { symptom.push_back("Y"); return "Y"; }`, and so forth.

Comment: Keep in mind that your function is receiving the vector by value as a copy so any changes you make to it will not be visible outside this function. You may want to pass the vector by reference or simply return the vector but without context of how you are using this in a [mcve] it is hard to give advice.

Comment: What are you planning to *do with* the return value? And what *value* should be returned? Are you expecting `.push_back` itself to return something? If so, what and why? And did you try reading the documentation for it?

Comment: what you actually want is vector.emplace_back and c++17 or newer, then that function returns a reference to the inserted element https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Answer (score 3):

The [`std::vector.push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) function has a `void` return type, so there is *no way* you can convert what it returns to *any* type (because it doesn't return anything).

However, there is the [`std::vector.back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) function, which returns a reference to the last element; so, you could make your conditional `push_back()` calls in the relevant blocks, then have a *single* return statement that 'retrieves' the element that was pushed:

```cpp
string yesno(string holder, vector<string> symptom)
{
    if (holder == "Y" || holder == "y") {
        symptom.push_back("Y");
    }
    else if (holder == "N" || holder == "n") {
        symptom.push_back("N");
    }
    else {
        cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
        symptom.push_back("-");
    }
    return symptom.back();
}
```

Also, as noted in the comments, you are passing your `symptom` vector *by value*, which means that a local copy will be used and any changes made to that will be lost when the function returns (the copy will be deleted). You may want to consider passing `symptom` by reference:

```cpp
string yesno(string holder, vector<string>& symptom) // Pass by reference!
{
    //...
```